# Is "covered wagons rolling access the prairies" wrong?

Tags: tense, british-english, present-continuous, collocations, dictionaries

I am using Oxford's Dictonary Advanced learner + Oxford's Collocations dictionary - 10th edition - mobile application (licensed). I seen

[image]

In my thought, it is *covered wagons **are** rolling access the prairies* .

Is *covered wagons rolling access the prairies* wrong?

Comment: None of those are intended to be complete sentences. The other example, *a long train of supply wagons* isn't a sentence either. Complete sentences start with a capital letter and end with a punctuation mark - that's just a sentence fragment, and cannot stand on its own grammatically.

Comment: There's an error in your question.  While it's not a full sentence, "covered wagons rolling **across** the prairies" is correct.  The example shown is not meant to be a complete sentence though.

Comment: It's absolutely fine as a sentence fragment. You could expand it to "The covered wagons rolling across the prairies could be seen from miles away."

Answer (score 3):

This example is a sentence fragment, not a complete sentence. In particular it is a noun phrase, headed by the noun "wagons" modified by the adjective "covered" and the participle "rolling across the prairies".

Note that the word is "across" not "access".

This is a sentence fragment, and not a complete sentence. You could use this sentence fragment in a full sentence, for example:

> I saw many covered wagons rolling across the prairies.

A dictionary might give an example of the use of a word that is not a complete sentence:

> Cat:
>
> > a cute cat with a loud purr

The example of use isn't a complete sentence.